# text from divs into array for sorting

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get all the text of a particular class into an array.

The below works theoretically, but it puts them into an object, not an array, and .map apparently is widely unsupported in most versions of IE :(

```
var valuesArr = $('.'+sort_column);
var valuesArr =  valuesArr.map(function(){return $(this).text().trim();});
```

Is there any way to get all the values into a plain and simple array that I'm just missing?

Thanks!

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.makeArray/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple iteration:

```
var array = [];

$(".elements").each(function() {
    array.push($.trim($(this).text()));
});

console.log(array);
```

Or with jQuery `map` method:

```
var array = $(".elements").map(function() {
    return $.trim($(this).text());
}).get();

console.log(array);​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/f6cmR/

Comment: any particular advantage to one or the other?

Comment: `.map()` returns a `jQuery object` not an `array`.

Comment: @thomas Implicitly the first iteration underlies of JQuery `map` method. The second can be considered as one line solution only. And yes, `map` returns object of `{ 0: value, 1: value, ... }`, which most browsers interpret as array (see log in demo). Both methods work fine in all browsers.

Comment: You'll want `.get()` after the `.map()` call to get an array.

Comment: @ThiefMaster Hm... I was thinking about that. From [JQuery specification](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/), `map()`: *Translate all items in an array or object to new array of items*. I do not see any problems in calling the resulting array "a pure array" somehow. Or what is the reason for using `get()`?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/map/ is the method you are using, not http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/

Comment: @ThiefMaster Dammit! :D I typed this comment to another question with another `map` method :) Of course here we can use `get` to get the pure array.

Answer (score 0):

Use [$.map](http://api.jquery.com/map/) like

```
var valuesArr = $('.'+sort_column);
var valuesArr =  $.map(valuesArr,function(){
                      return $(this).text().trim();
                     }).get();
```

`$.map` return an jQuery object.

> jQuery obects are array-like, but they are not arrays! The reason of
>   calling .get() at the end of the .map() call is to turn that jQuery
>   object into a true array. The elements of that array are the values
>   returned by the callback.

Comment: `$.map` iterates over a set of elements, I dont think it's an issue with IE. Can you be more specific of what IE problem you are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$.makeArray()` to convert jQuery object to an array and then map text from elements:

```
var valuesArr = $.makeArray($('.elements'))
    .map(function() {
        return $(this).text().trim();
    });
```

Comment: Or just use `.get()` on the jQuery object.